# How to find the highest value of each row in a 2d array(matrix) c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Each line represent the grades of a random stundent
Each column represents the grades of a random subject
Find the highest grade obtained by each student
The expected output is:

```
The student 0 has the highest grade =  10
The student 1 has the highest grade =  10
The student 2 has the highest grade =  10
The student 3 has the highest grade =  10
The student 4 has the highest grade =  10
The student 5 has the highest grade =  9
```

Here is the array:

```
double[,] grades;
    grades = new double[6, 4];
    grades[0, 0] = 8; grades[0, 1] = 10; grades[0, 2] = 9; grades[0, 3] = 7;
    grades[1, 0] = 7; grades[1, 1] = 9; grades[1, 2] = 8; grades[1, 3] = 10;
    grades[2, 0] = 6; grades[2, 1] = 6; grades[2, 2] = 7; grades[2, 3] = 10;
    grades[3, 0] = 6; grades[3, 1] = 5; grades[3, 2] = 10; grades[3, 3] = 7;
    grades[4, 0] = 10; grades[4, 1] = 4; grades[4, 2] = 9; grades[4, 3] = 8;
    grades[5, 0] = 9; grades[5, 1] = 7; grades[5, 2] = 5; grades[5, 3] = 9;
```

Here is my code :

```
double maxGrade;   
maxGrade = grades[0, 0];
    for(int student = 0; student < note.GetLength(0); student++)
{
      for(int subject = 0; subject < note.GetLength(1); subject++)
{
        if (grades[student, subject] > maxGrade)
            maxGrade = grades[student, subject];          
}
Console.WriteLine("The student " + student + " has the highest grade =  " + maxGrade);
}
My output is :
The student 0 has the highest grade =  10
The student 1 has the highest grade =  10
The student 2 has the highest grade =  10
The student 3 has the highest grade =  10
The student 4 has the highest grade =  10
The student 5 has the highest grade =  10
```

Comment: Soooo, people don't like doing your homework. Write about what you have tried, and what is not working. Try to ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep the `maxGrade` between students, which causes the wrong result. You need to reinitialize it for each student:

```
for (int student = 0; student < note.GetLength(0); student++)
{
    double maxGrade = grades[student, 0];

    // Note you can start the iteration at 1, since you already grabbed index 0
    for (int subject = 1; subject < note.GetLength(1); subject++)
    {
        if (grades[student, subject] > maxGrade) {
            maxGrade = grades[student, subject];
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("The student " + student + " has the highest grade =  " + maxGrade);
}
```